# Error ensamblador usando msx88 "Falta la directiva END"

Tags: ensamblador

Estoy aprendiendo ensamblador, usando msx88, pero ningún código funciona, ni siquiera los ejemplos.
Ya he reiniciado, y hecho la instalación al pie de la letra, pero aún así no funciona :(

[image: Uso archivo de suma de los ejemplos]

Código de ejemplo:

```
ORG 2000H
MOV AX,20H
MOV DX,30H
ADD AX,DX
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado
Me faltaba otra instrucción `END` (no sé porqué en algunos computadores lo exige)

Quedaría así

```
ORG 2000H
MOV AX,20H
MOV DX,30H
ADD AX,DX
END 
END
```